# List all regular n-gons with up to 80 sides that can be origami constructible.

Tags: geometry, origami

I know an origami constructible regular n-gons are those with $n=2^a3^bρ≥3$ sides where ρ is a product of distinct Pierpoint primes (i.e prime of the form $2^u3^v+1$).

So, the Pierpont primes (p) I am using are: 3, 5, 7, 13, 17, 19, and 37.  Now I am confused about how to solve for n.

Comment: Relevant OEIS entries: [A122254: *Numbers with 3-smooth Euler's totient*](https://oeis.org/A122254), [A005109: *Pierpont primes*](https://oeis.org/A005109).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just take $a=0,1,2,3\dots, b=0,1,2,3,\dots$ and calculate as many cases as you want until you get tired.  So $a=1,b=4,\rho=5$ gives $n=2^13^45=810$ is one case.